# How can I pass selected item of select list to controller action as parameter

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to sort data based of user selection but I am not being able to pass sleeted item to controller action.

In My View:

```
<form asp-action="Explore" asp-controller="Venue" method="Post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select title="Sort by">
      <option name="name"> <a asp-controller="Venue" asp-action="Explore" asp-route-sortby="Name">Name</a> </option>
      <option name="rating">Rating</option>
      <option name="rating">Price</option>

    </select>
  </div>
```

In My Controller:

```
public async Task < IActionResult > Explore(
  string sortby) {
  return View(_context.Hotels.OrdeyrByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList();
  }
```

Comment: These code only have html code only. Please provide more information like which framework you are using, the controller endpoint, sample data.

Comment: I am using aspnet core mvc

Comment: You have to use AJAX method that will help you pass your variable to the Controller's action method. Google it: How to use ajax to pass data to controller in mvc core.

Comment: I didnot found any tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are hitting the `Action`, add a `name` attribute to your `<select>`.

So something like this:

```
<select title="Sort by" name="sortby">
```

Bear in mind that the name must match the parameter name in the action. Also, you will need to add `value` attribute to all your `<option>` tags, like this:

```
<option name="rating" value="rating">Rating</option>
```

Comment: thanks but how can i hit controller action on drop down change

Comment: That is a separate question